# How can I properly center an infowindow in Google Maps API V3 in a narrow width map canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a page as an example of what I am talking about:

http://www.gamecodemonkey.com/test/maptest.html

I have a narrow map canvas with an infowindow in it. When you click on the marker, it will usually center properly to contain the marker and the window, but for some reason, if you click on that marker, it will sometimes be off the screen on the right. You can also keep clicking the marker and it seems to shift from the correct centering to being off screen on the right. I've also tried manually centering the marker position with the map.setCenter() call, but it does the same thing.

Is this a bug or is there a better way to center the marker and the info window?

Code snippet from example link:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: -25.363882,
      lng: 131.044922
    },
    zoom: 8
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  var contentString = "<div style='width: 150px; height: 150px;'>My Info Window</div>"

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 209px;
  height: 484px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As geocodezip said in his(deleted) answer: the InfoWindow is too large.

You set a width of 150px for the content, but the window is larger(because of padding and the close-button).
The API didn't only try to show the complete window, it also tries to place the window so that it's not covered by controls.

That's what forces the offset, because on the left there are the zoom+streetView-controls.

There is no general solution. For the given map/infowindow you may place these controls at `TOP_CENTER` (and use a addionally control to push the 2 built-controls to the left)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n7xsjhsw/